# How to send multiple request by using post method

Tags: talend

I want to send multiple http request by using post method.
I'm using tHttpRequest to call api like this :

[image]

I'm using post method with parameters read from .txt file. Like below :

```
login_id=7777&system_cd=1&role_cd=1
login_id=9999999999999&system_cd=1&role_cd=1
```

It works. But it sends two requests of first parameters line

```
login_id=7777&system_cd=1&role_cd=1
```

But the second parameters line, was not sent

```
login_id=9999999999999&system_cd=1&role_cd=1
```

How to send multiple request by using post method ?

---

### Update

Thank you so much!!! It’s works perfectly for me.

But it write only  success response to log file

I want to write all response (success response and not success response) in same file

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Use a tHttpRequest for every request you want to make. If the amount is dynamic, use a tJavaRow component and write the request yourself, looping around the URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to issue a post request for each line in your parameters file. Here's how you can achieve this :

```
tFileInputFullRow -- Main -- tFlowToIterate -- iterate -- tFixedFlowInput -- Main -- tFileOutputRaw (temp file) -- OnComponentOk -- tHttpRequest_1 (read temp file) -- main -- tFileOutputDelimited_1
```

What this does is, loop over the lines from your parameters file, and for each line, create a file containing that single line (read the line in `tFixedFlowInput` using the global variable set by `tFlowToIterate` and output it to a file), then call your `tHttpRequest` by specifying the newly created file to read parameters from.

**Edit**

From what I understand, you want to write the response as well as the error message (if any), to the same file. Here's how you can do that :

[image]

In the `If` trigger, you need to test the response code of `tHttpRequest_1` :

```
((Integer)globalMap.get("tHttpRequest_1_RESPONSE_CODE")) != 200
```

If the request returns an error code, then you read the error message `(String)globalMap.get("tHttpRequest_1_ERROR_MESSAGE")` and write it to the same physical file in `tFileOutputDelimited_2`

Comment: I have been updated my question, Please help me one more time

Comment: Thanks bro, It's  perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the file containing your request body to `Post parameters from file`

Something like this.

```
{
 "login": [
 {
   "login_id":9999999999999,
   "system_cd":1,
   "role_cd":1  
 },
 {
   "login_id":8888888888,
   "system_cd":3,
   "role_cd":2
 }
 ]
}
```

[image]

Can refer to this doc. https://help.talend.com/reader/MjIZDoU6r0vLbCpGh5GAcg/WjbsVyUCV2MD8C7_uVYKRA